# iOS what is the highest level networking abstraction that is appropriate for handling bi-directional sync over http?

Tags: ios, http, network-programming, synchronization, afnetworking-2

I'm looking at the [Apple networking guidelines that suggest that the user should try to work with the highest level of abstraction possible](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220) when dealing with networking.

I'm working on a client-server app, where the server is master, and an iOS device is slave. These communicate over HTTP, establishing a connection that lives for the lifetime of the app's usage session. The app and the server synchronize assets over this connection.

My question is - **what level of abstraction is appropriate for implementing bi-directional sync over HTTP?** Is it sockets, NSURLConnection, some AFNetworking subclass, input/output streams?

Comment: I think this is first and foremost a question about your app's problem domain. Without knowing how much data you need to synchronize, how those changes can be expressed, or what user experience you want to provide there isn't enough information to make an accurate suggestion. Whatever you do will be a tradeoff between responsiveness, power consumption, data consistency, and implementation cost. What do you want to prioritize?

Comment: For the most part, the data is strings and JSON objects under 1Kb. Ideally I expect to keep a local cache of data to prevent having to make a network call each time a view controller is presented. This means I need to think about some kind of background sync that checks the server for updates every X seconds while the app is running and initiates interface updates.

Comment: In particular, I'm concerned that a server cannot easily target a particular device by IP, so I would expect a device to initiate some sort of connection and the server to keep this connection alive for data exchange. I'm not sure what kind of connection this is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible good answers to this. I think all I can do is offer one pattern which has worked well for me but it may not apply to your needs and use cases. To restate my comment above "whatever you do will be a tradeoff between responsiveness, power consumption, data consistency, and implementation cost."

The level of abstraction I aim for is a set of service objects which expose an interface in terms of the application's domain models. The rest of the app, primarily objects in the controller layer, should be able to communicate with these services by passing models to methods (e.g. "fetchUserWithId:userId" or "createUser:user") and without any awareness of the urls, paths, or HTTP verbs involved at the network layer.

Those service objects can map domain model operations into paths, HTTP verbs, and possibly request bodies or headers. In most cases I find that the services themselves can then share a lower level service which accepts those values and constructs the actual HTTP request. This provides a single location to configure host names, set global headers, and manage a request queue via NSURLRequest, NSURLSession, AFNetworking, or whatever library you prefer.

I'll include completion blocks on my service object methods so that controllers can be notified of success or failure but try not to use those blocks to pass models back up to the controller layer. Instead I prefer to have controllers monitor Core Data or some other persistence layer and react to changes. That way controllers remain flexible and respond to any update in the models they are concerned with and do not assume that they are aware of all possible sources of changes to those models.

So far none of this addresses how you should check for remote changes to your models. The best option may be to design a system which does not need to do so. What if your client obtained a set of recent changes only when posting data to the server, could it still provide a good user experience? Could the server use push notifications to occasionally notify clients of updates?

If you must check for changes sockets or long polling are usually more responsive than short polling but it may be hard for roaming mobile clients to keep those connections open. All of these approaches also tend to keep the client's radios active and consume lots of power in the process.

Without knowing more about the problem I'd default to short polling but try to design interactions which allow this to be as infrequent as possible (e.g. one check when the app resumes). I also use HTTP features (etags, if-modified-since, or custom content ranges) to limit the size of responses when there are no changes. If you have a good service layer managing network requests that also gives you a good place to introduce rate limiting. Allowing controllers to express interest to fetching up to date information but deferring to the services to throttle or batch requests based on what the rest of the app is doing (e.g. don't repeat the same request if those models were updated recently unless the user deliberately triggered the action).